# .war file won't be updated

Tags: eclipse, gwt, tomcat, ant, war

I have an old project, built using Google Web Toolkit in Eclipse. When I created it, I did the following steps, in order to get the .war file

1. GWT Compile Project
2. Run the following Ant script

   ```
   <project name="The" basedir="." default="default">

    <target name="default" depends="buildwar,deploy"></target>

    <target name="buildwar">
       <war basedir="war" destfile="The.war" webxml="war/WEB-INF/web.xml">
           <exclude name="WEB-INF/**" />
           <webinf dir="war/WEB-INF/">
               <include name="**/*.jar" />
           </webinf>
       </war>
    </target>

    <target name="deploy">
       <copy file="The.war" todir="." />
    </target>

   </project>
   ```
3. Get the .war file

Now, I had to change a port in my project, so I changed it in my code and did the same steps in order to get the .war

However, when I deploy my updated project in Tomcat, it still makes requests to the old port number (I found this reading catalina.out)

So, What can I do in order to get a new, fresh .war ???

Comment: First clean the folder where you are deploying the war file.

Comment: meaning? the folder in my project or the folder in the web server?
Actually, I've tried it a lot of times, and each time before doing these steps i delete the previous .war (in my project and in the server)

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention it, but did you change the ports in tomcat? I assume you did, but I just want to cover all possibilities.

Comment: yes, I did...I even tried to introduce white spaces somewhere in the code, so that the specific file is changed in all cases